# Handling wsgi requests in my application

Tags: python, wsgi, uwsgi

I've hit some conceptual road-block on something that should be simple.

I have a single-threaded, plain python application, which runs indefinitely.

I would like to be able to query information about the internal state of the application from the web, via an http request.

Most of the models I have seen for this, e.g. python's WSGIServer from flup.server.fcgi,  require me to provide a callback function to handle a request. The callback then becomes the starting point of my program.

Instead of reworking my application's logic to fit this model of: request-->callback, I need to be able to hadnle requests within my own application's logic. For example, periodically throughout the execution of my application, I would check if there are any pending http/wsgi requests, handle them, and continue.

Do I have to open a sockets myself and deal with all the socket logic in order to achieve this? I don't necessarily mind, but I suspect I don't need to reinvent the wheel here.

Am I thinking about this incorrectly?

Comment: You could have your main app periodically store the state somewhere, and the WSGI part would publish it when requested.

Comment: I actually solved this problem. I will add the answer below